# Virtual Keyboard Only Visible when I touch the editable part of screen and not on mouse click

Tags: qt, qml

I working on a qt qml application and I want to use the virtual keyboard feature of qt quick. But I want the virtual keyboard to appear only when I touch my laptop screen. The current solution of mine brings virtual keyboard up even when I click mouse on the editable area.

I tried to a lot but couldnt get close to solution. I was thinking of suppressing the mouse click event on the Input Panel but couldnt figure out how

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 720
height: 480
minimumWidth: 400
minimumHeight:350

TabView {
    id:frame
    anchors.fill: parent
    style: myTabViewStyle
    implicitHeight: 100
Tab{
        id: setupPage
        objectName:"TabParentOfSetup"
        enabled: true
        title: "Setup"
        active: true
        SetupTab { }
   }

Tab{
        id:tabletab
        objectName: "TabParentOfTable"
        title: "Table"
        TableTab{}
   }

 }

statusBar: StatusBar
{
Label{
    id: label
}
}
InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        y: Qt.inputMethod.visible ? parent.height - inputPanel.height : 
           parent.height
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.left: parent.left
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something like this when you want to show/hide InputPanel :     function setInputPanelEnabled( myBool )
    {
        idInputPanel.active = false;
        idInputPanel.visible = idInputPanel.active;
    }

Comment: How it will be visible on touching the screen, can you please explain a little more